# Python Subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm beginner in python programming and while I apply an example of subprocess module i encountered an error

The example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

handle = subprocess. Popen("ls", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
handle.stdout.read()
```

The Encountered Error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' objecthas no attribute 'Popen'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you called your `.py` file as `subprocess.py`.

Change it to another name. Python trying to import your file as `subprocess`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The `file.py` is called `example.py`. The command is executed correctly in the python shell but when saved in file this error happens

Comment: @PythonLover add output of `print subprocess.__file_`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. How can I do that

Answer (score -2):

.Popen contains SPACE between . and Popen